# TTY console on one monitor, X/Wayland on another

Tags: multiple-monitors

Using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, with a dual monitor configuration, is it possible for X (or Wayland) to be configured only to use one monitor, and the other one to be pure TTY (as in, not a terminal emulator, just default boot-style TTY, unknown/unused by any GUI).

The reason I'd like this is because I have a very high resolution [5k x 2k monitor](https://www.msi.com/Content-Creation-Monitor/Prestige-PS341WU) as primary, and my secondary one is much lower DPI. I don't like the idea that X-scaling "uses more resources" because this suggests some on-the-fly interpolation scheme which, apart from introduced latency, will almost certainly not play nice with sub-pixel font rendering, and will probably screw up integer scaling on graphical programs. Wayland by contrast just doesn't work with this configuration - multiple problems and basically crashes. So essentially I'd like to code in a terminal on the low-res TTY monitor, and have the main high DPI monitor run X (or wayland) with 100% scaling, no screwing around, though I'd probably [raise the DPI setting](https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_set_DPI_in_Xorg).

Is this possible on one video card (Radeon VII). If not, would it be possible if running a secondary video card at the same time?

If it *is* possible, how would I switch focus of the keyboard between TTY monitor and GUI(Gnome) monitor? Run some kind of bash script to toggle focus maybe?

Comment: Would it be feasible to run a separate box via terminal like raspberryPi through a remote connection (network like ssh) or KVM or something like that? A physically separate machine could accomplish this with a bit of latency but executed faithful to your wants.

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly not a definitive answer, as in most cases of an answer for the negative.

I think what you mean to accomplish is likely not possible, as all of the solutions for booting into text mode do so at the `grub` level.
I hardly see a way that `grub` tells the OS to perform your intended actions.

**Sources**:

1. [How to boot to text only mode? Problem with laptop with Nvidia GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854013/how-to-boot-to-text-only-mode-problem-with-laptop-with-nvidia-gpu)
2. https://dannyda.com/2019/06/19/turn-off-display-automatically-on-ubuntu-18-04-server-with-text-boot/
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17027/how-to-set-the-resolution-in-text-consoles-troubleshoot-when-any-vga-fail (very old)
4. https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/how-to-boot-to-console-text-mode-in.html

**(Possibly) Related**, and perhaps helping in finding a workaround, YMMV:

1. [Dual Monitor Setup : Grub loader goes to HDTV even if it is turned off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418607/dual-monitor-setup-grub-loader-goes-to-hdtv-even-if-it-is-turned-off)
2. [Forcing grub menu to external monitor connected to laptop via HDMI/VGA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712111/forcing-grub-menu-to-external-monitor-connected-to-laptop-via-hdmi-vga)
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatOneCard
4. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13619/how-do-i-prevent-xorg-using-my-linux-laptops-display-panel
5. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead
6. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extreme_Multihead

Comment: I think so too. TTY is useful because it bypasses non-essentials (gui) to operate if needed in an 'emergency'. Having X/Wayland running while in TTY would sort of defeat the utility of TTY fundamentally. GUI terminals are the equivalent to what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Bounty awarded to you for the great links, but I still wish that we had found a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried for something a few years ago similar to this (my setup was for a set of televisions as opposed to a super high-def monitor) and I do not think this is possible at this point :( It's a good idea, and should exist, but I can't think of a real way to do this besides effectively having a dual-setup where one system hosts the tty and the other mounts that system 'remotely' for gui use. I wish I had solved it back then.

Comment: yes, I believe that you'd need to have 2 systems, of sorts.  You could set up the "TTY" on the Serial port, and then put the serial port on the second screen, using a raspberry pi, or equivalent.  You can't easily use 1 system because how would you select the screen of the TTY if it wasn't graphical?